# How to get objects to follow camera rotation

Tags: camera

What I want to have done is have an object follow the camera's rotation so that the camera is always seeing a specific face. Think of it this way: of any of you have played Minecraft, you may have noticed that the particles that are rendered in-game can never be viewed from the side. The rotate when you rotate, because they're two-dimensional and it wouldn't make a lot of sense to see them from their very depth-less side. So to speak, what I'm actually trying to do is a Minecraft themed scene. I'm trying to imitate those particles rendering within Blender. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a "Track to" constraint to your object. The target should be the camera, and the To/Up values depend on what's appropriate for your model.

[image]